# Multi-Select DropDown: Disable selected option only (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, disabled-control

I need to disable each selection option in a dropdown upon a user selecting it.

Right now the code below disables only values with the value of "red," in the dropdown because I have the value="red," hard-coded. How would I make it grab the users selection and disable that selection only?

**(Updated snippet)**

```js
 $(".mutliSelect select").on("change", function() {
    
        var displayTitle = $(this).val() + "";
        
        if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
          $(".hida").show();
        } else {

        $("option[value*='red']").prop('disabled',true);
         
        var p_elem = $("<span />")
            .attr("class", "categoryBubble")
            .attr("title", displayTitle)
            .text(displayTitle);
    
        var other_span = $("<span />")
            .on("click", foo)
            .addClass("Xout")
            .text("x");

          $(p_elem).append(other_span);
          $(".multiSel").append(p_elem);

          $(".hida").hide();
        }
      });
```

Comment: `this` within the context of `$(this).is(":selected")` is the `<select>`, not an option, so that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also your initial setting of `var title` is completely overwritten by `title = $(this).val() + "";` so that's a logic error

Comment: thanks for all the help ... I was able to create a multi-select/dropdown that disables each option selected.  Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chaser7016/sghv4fz7/12/

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple in vanilla Javascript:

```js
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  for (let option of this.querySelectorAll('option')) {
    option.disabled = [...this.selectedOptions].includes(option)
  }  
})
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

This assumes you only want the currently picked option disabled, and all others enabled. If that's not correct, please leave a comment specifying what exactly you need.

Comment: Thank you!  Based on your feedback and the feedback above I am extremely close to solving this in jQuery.  Stuck on how to properly format the following   $('option="' + displayTitle + '"').prop('disabled',true);

Comment: Why complicate things with jQuery? The native API seems so much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with jQuery, here's another simple solution (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brimer/wamko3f8/14/)):

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var colors = [];
    
    $.each($(".colors option:selected"), function(){
     $(this).prop('disabled', true);
     $('.selected').append($(this).val(), ', ');
    });
    
    $('.selected').append('<br/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="colors" multiple="multiple" size="8">
    <option>black</option>
    <option>red</option>
    <option>green</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>white</option>
    <option>purple</option>
    <option>orange</option>
    <option>yellow</option>
</select>

<div class="selected"></div>
```

Notice that to get the value from the selected option itself, you need `$(".colors option:selected")`.

Also notice that you can't assume there will be only one option selected at a time. The `$.each()` method processes each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help S.O. community!

It allowed me to come up with the following solution for a multi-select dropdown that shows each selected item above the select and each item selected is disabled within the dropdown.

Here is the fiddle of it working in full with HTML, CSS and the below JS https://jsfiddle.net/chaser7016/sghv4fz7/12/

```js
$(".mutliSelect select").on("change", function() {
    
        var displayTitle = $(this).val() + "";
        
        $('option[value="' + displayTitle + '"]').prop('disabled',true);
         
        var p_elem = $("<span />")
            .attr("class", "categoryBubble")
            .attr("title", displayTitle)
            .text(displayTitle);
    
        var other_span = $("<span />")
            .on("click", foo)
            .addClass("Xout")
            .text("x");

          $(p_elem).append(other_span);
          $(".multiSel").append(p_elem);

          $(".hida").hide();

          function foo() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            $('option[value="' + displayTitle + '"]').prop('disabled', false);
          }

      });
```